# C# I'm getting null from Task or Dispatcher

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, dispatcher

I have this code:

```
public void OpenReport(XtraReport report, int zoomMode)
    {
        //Show loading animation.
        MainInterfaceViewModel.State = States.Busy;
        //Load the report, then navigate to the ReportViewer
        Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadReport(report, zoomMode));
        //After completing the task hide the loading animation
        tsk.ContinueWith(obj => MainInterfaceViewModel.State = States.Idle);
     }

private void LoadReport(XtraReport report, int zoomMode)
    {
        ReportViewerViewModel reportViewerViewModel;
        reportViewerViewModel = new ReportViewerViewModel(report, zoomMode);
        ReportViewer.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => ReportViewer.DataContext = reportViewerViewModel)) ;
        Frame.Navigate(ReportViewer);
    }
```

But when the OpenReport method is executed I get an empty ReportViewer, why I'm getting this problem while I passed the Report to the method ?
The image bellow shows the result I get.

[The results I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWYOr.png)

**EDIT:**

When I change the OpenReport method to the following code I get the report shown inside the report viewer but the UI freezes when the report is preparing (about 3 seconds).

```
public void OpenReport(XtraReport report, int zoomMode)
    {
        //Show loading animation.
        MainInterfaceViewModel.State = States.Busy;
        //Load the report
        ReportViewerViewModel reportViewerViewModel;
        reportViewerViewModel = new ReportViewerViewModel(report, zoomMode);
        ReportViewer.DataContext = reportViewerViewModel;
        //Navigate to the ReportViewer
        Frame.Navigate(ReportViewer);
        //Hide the loading animation.
        MainInterfaceViewModel.State = States.Idle;
    }
```

Comment: Where does `report` come from?

Comment: The report come from a method on an other class, I tried all this without the Task and the dispatcher, it's working but very slowly and the UI freezes a lot.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve by merely executing Dispatch.Invoke() from another thread/Task.

Comment: I'm trying to show a report on a report viewer called ReportViewer by loading the report to it and than navigate to it thru:  Frame.Navigate(ReportViewer);

Comment: I'll recommend to use Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.StartNew. Because as per MSDN blog.

Task.Factory.StartNew doesn’t exactly roll off the tongue, at least not quickly enough for something that’s used in such primary scenarios as easily offloading work to background processing threads.
Please go through following likes

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @TotaloDotoNeto, Thanks for the advice and the helpful links, but have you any solutions for my problem ?

Comment: Are you able to use .net 4.5 or greater?

Comment: Why are you using a threadpool thread just to queue work back onto the UI thread?

Comment: Yes @Gusdor I'm able to use .net 4.5

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Because the UI freezes when trying to load the report and navigate to the report viewer.

Comment: Can you define _"an empty report viewer"_ a little better? Is it null or does it have a null view model?

Comment: @Gusdor, I edited the question, please see the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

As @TotaloDotoNeto tried to point out, `Task.StartNew` is sometimes dangerous method to use, as it uses the `TaskScheduler.Current` not `TaskScheduler.Default` property, which is quite uneasy to deal with. Stephen Cleary has [a great article regarding differences between `StartNew` and `Run` methods](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)., and if you are interested, here is [another one from Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). So, first of all I suggest you to switch to `Run` method:

```
Task tsk = Task.Run(() => LoadReport(report, zoomMode));
```

Second, let's see what your code is doing: you start a `Task`, and inside that task your are using some background logic (`Dispatcher.Invoke`) and foreground logic (`Frame.Navigate`). I think that that problem you have is caused by your code for `Frame` being executed not in UI-thread. So, you have two options:

```
// add the Navigate method to the invoking delegate
ReportViewer.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{
    ReportViewer.DataContext = reportViewerViewModel;
    Frame.Navigate(ReportViewer);
}));
```

or make your code `async`, something like this:

```
public async Task OpenReport(XtraReport report, int zoomMode)
{
    // Show loading animation.
    MainInterfaceViewModel.State = States.Busy;
    // Asynchronously wait for the model to load
    var task = await Task.Run(() => LoadReport(report, zoomMode));
    // process the model after it's being loaded
    ReportViewer.DataContext = task.Result;
    // Navigate to the ReportViewer
    Frame.Navigate(ReportViewer);
    // After completing the task hide the loading animation
    MainInterfaceViewModel.State = States.Idle;
}

private async Task<ReportViewerViewModel> LoadReport(XtraReport report, int zoomMode)
{
    return new ReportViewerViewModel(report, zoomMode);
}
```

Note that in second case you have to rewrite your code [to `async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). [Another article about `async/await` keywords](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and some useful article about how to [do not block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), if you are interested in this theme.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but neither of the two options is working, I'm getting the same result. when I use synchronous code the report shows normal with a preceding UI freeze but I get a blank ReportViewer with asynchronous code. something is wrong, but what is it ? I'm feeling fool.

Comment: Where does your `Navigate` call lay? I think that the problem is that it's being executed before you got your datasource. Can you provide the code you've tried?

Comment: The code in my last question edit works but with UI freezing, and the code you provided does not work, I get a blank ReportViewer..

Comment: Did you check in debug what exactly being returned in `task.Result`?

Comment: Yes I did, it returns a ReportViewerViewModel loaded with the passed report, and this is what makes me feeling fool :(

Comment: Wow, that's very strange. Try to usethis: `configureawait(false)` on the task populating the view model. May be it will help somehow

Comment: @AxelDesigns And how do you call the `async OpenReport` method?

Comment: The `configureawait(false)`  does not work, and I'm calling the    `async OpenReport` like this `await Task.Run (() => OpenReport(new EmployeesListReport(), zoomMode));`

Comment: Hmm, seems like your component doesn't work well with async code. Try to excplicitly wait for outer task or run `OpenReport` directly. Can't suggest something other than this :(

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts you did for me @VMAtm